# How to render image using markdown in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I have `![Alt text](/RSA1.jpg )` in my markdown file. When I read the markdown file and render it is showing the alt text instead of image and when i inspect there is this line as below as below:

```html
<img alt="Alt text" src="/RSA1.jpg">
```

How can I render image???
I am using `markdown to jsx` as markdown parser.

Answer (score 1):

> Markdown for the component era
> MDX is an authorable format that lets you seamlessly write JSX in your Markdown documents. You can import components, such as interactive charts or alerts, and embed them within your content. This makes writing long-form content with components a blast

https://mdxjs.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure RSA1.jpg is in your public folder, and it should render the image properly. The markdown parser can't find images unless they're in the public folder.